# Three input/output generalization of 50:50 beamsplitter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics

A symmetric 50:50 beamsplitter can be represented by a unitary 2x2 matrix acting on a vector of creation operators for the input states:

$$    \begin{pmatrix}
    \hat{a}_c^\dagger\\
    \hat{a}_d^\dagger
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    \hat{a}_a^\dagger\\
    \hat{a}_b^\dagger
    \end{pmatrix}.$$

This gives rise to interesting effects such as the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect where a (1,1)-output is impossible for a (1,1)-input.

Is it possible to generalize this two-mode beamsplitter to a three-mode beamsplitter where each input photon has the same probability to end up in any of the three output modes?

My own attempt:
I tried to construct a 3x3 matrix representation myself following the principles of the two-mode beamsplitter but was unsure how to make it unitary. The way I interpret the two-mode matrix is each element $U_{i,j}$ is the amplitude for a photon in mode $i$ to end up in mode $j$, meaning for example that the only difference between $U_{1,1}$ and $U_{1,2}$ is a $\frac{\pi}{2}$ phase $\exp(i\frac{\pi}{2})=i$, since we are dealing with a symmetric beamsplitter. I wanted to use roots of unity for the 3x3 beamsplitter matrix, to represent an equal probability for a photon to end up in any of the output modes, meaning only a phase difference between their amplitude:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}}{\sqrt{3}}\\
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\end{pmatrix}.$$

However, from this point on I was unable to fill out the rest of the matrix as I realised I had no idea if this was going to be a unitary matrix or not.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega=e^{2 \pi i/3}$.  Then the Hadamard-type matrix
\begin{align}
H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&1\\
1&\omega&\omega^2\\
1&\omega^2&\omega
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
will do the trick of providing equal $1/3:1/3:1/3$ splitting.

For a discussion of a generalized HOM effect see

> Lim, Yuan Liang, and Almut Beige. "Generalized Hong–Ou–Mandel experiments with bosons and fermions." New Journal of Physics 7.1 (2005): 155.

with [OpenAccess version available](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/7/1/155/pdf).

Comment: thank you very much. This is exactly what I am looking for